# What is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\mathrm{i} n \cosh{x}) \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I'm hoping to determine the value of the following integral:
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\mathrm{i} n \cosh{x}) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Here is a plot of the integrand as a function of $x$ with parameter $n$ varying from 0 to 10.

[image]

The integral appears to not converge. However, it is known that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\mathrm{i} n x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\pi \delta(n)$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function. Is it possible for the first integral to be expressed similarly using Dirac delta notation?

Comment: This integral is related to the Hankel function for which an [integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039599/what-is-int-infty-infty-exp-mathrmi-n-coshx-mathrmdx) is $${H^{(1)}_{\nu}}\left(z\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\nu\pi i}}{\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iz\cosh t-\nu t}\mathrm{d}t$$ Here, $\nu=0$.

Comment: @PaulEnta, then for real $z$ the integral doesn't exist in the usual sense, does it? Or is the function analytically continued somehow?

Comment: @YuriyS The principal branch of the function has a branch cut along the negative reals. See [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.ii) for example.

Comment: The representation $$Y_{0}\left(x\right)=-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(x\cosh t\right)\,
\mathrm{d}t$$ from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E9) may be also helpful.